# Есть примеры верстки таких штук?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите логику построения такого элемента? Желательно живые примеры.

Comment: Есть точно готовые библиотеки для javascript

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/

Comment: или вот - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic